# How to access the controls on UIView which is added to a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UIViewController in storyboard that includes a scrollView.

I want to put two UIImageViews and some UILabels on it.

the idea that I am thinking is : create a .xib file. Put a UIView on it, an then set my UIImageview and labels on this UIView.

Finally add my UIView which is a .xib file to my UIScrollView like this:

```
 NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OfferView" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *newPageView = [views lastObject];
self.newPageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
newPageView.frame = frame;
[self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];
[self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:newPageView];
```

Now I want to set Text and image for the controls on the UIView programatically in my UIViewController. I try this but it did not work:

```
OfferUIView *offer2 = [[OfferUIView alloc] init];;
offer2.labelCompany.text = @"some text";
```

I also defined `OfferUIView` in the interface of ViewController and then synchronize, but it did not help also:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) OfferUIView *offerView;
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Why not layout the content in your storyboard so that you have an easy way of connecting views to outlets in your view controller?

Comment: because I want to add a UIView to my scrollView, I cant create a UIView alone in storyboard, so I use .xib file. if you think it is not a good approach please write a complete answer for me and I will look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the pointer for your `OfferView` when you load the nib to your `offerView` property

```
NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OfferView" owner:self options:nil];
self.offerView = [views lastObject];
self.offerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
self.offerView.frame = frame;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.offerView];
[self.pageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:self.offerView];
```

And when you want to change it:

```
self.offerView.labelCompany.text = @"some text";
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work, by the way I found another solution with using `tag`. Are you sure that your solution work?

Comment: Yes, it should. Are you sure you're changing the text after you've added the view?

Comment: Thanks, Now it worked, do you think this idea is better or using tag? and please tell me your reason.

Comment: Since `viewWithTag:` performs a search on the view and all its subviews, it's more complex (requires more computation) than just using the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

OfferUiView has to "**initWithFrame**" as it is required method for any view of class 'UIView' or set a frame to this view.Since u have subclassed UIView include initWithFrame as its constructor  Further, since u have programmatically allocated the OfferUIView u have to add this view to your currentview i.e [self.view addSubView:offer2];

Answer (score 0):

You can set a unique label for the `tag` and you can search for the label in the parentView like this:

```
UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[parentView viewWithTag: 10321];
```